# Updating md5 to sha512 authorizenet

Tags: php, md5, payment-gateway, authorize.net, sha512

I am updating the md5 to sha512 for DPM authorizenet- 
Please help me out -

I am not getting it work.

see code change -

while generating fingerprint for x_hp_hash -

from md5 -

```
if (function_exists('hash_hmac')) {

return hash_hmac("md5", $api_login_id . "^" . $fp_sequence . "^" .

 $fp_timestamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $transaction_key); 
}

return bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $api_login_id . "^" . $fp_sequence . "^" . $fp_timestamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $transaction_key));
```

to sha512 -

```
$signature_key = hex2bin($signature_key);

if (function_exists('hash_hmac')) {

return hash_hmac("sha512", $api_login_id . "^" . $fp_sequence . "^" .

 $fp_timestamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $signature_key); 

}

return bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA512, $api_login_id . "^" . $fp_sequence . "^" . $fp_timestamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $signature_key));
```

While getting reponse and comparing the x_sha_hash value
 from md5 -

```
if(strtoupper(md5($this->md5_setting . $this->api_login_id . $this

->transaction_id . $amount)) == $this->md5_hash){
        //valid
 } else{
        //not valid
 }
```

Changed to sha512 -

```
$this->signature_key = hex2bin($this->signature_key);

$string = '^'.$this->api_login_id.'^'.$this->transaction_id.'^'.$amount.'^';

if(strtoupper(HASH_HMAC('sha512', $string, $this->signature_key)) == $this->SHA2_Hash){
  //valid

} else{
  //not valid

}
```

What I am doing wrong?
When validating the transaction at my end it is saying please check your md5 setting. It validates on the basis of last code shown in the snippet.

my signature Key = E284BDC12A45A7F5B0933A352EB1C3F25E91A3B92360693D94E4366190EF12E78F6CFE8601751F719DA7A72ABBA117BF0161F8A1DD894DADE3C56A838D8355AD

**x_hp_hash** submitting using the second code snippet (i.e sha512 fingerprint)
x_hp_hash = b4c9e1878f88aa9c4f808761ed8ceee71ab117cc0f1297b2d850e28351f08fc52bd528a7538c832568c674a1d5095ead1a5383a626c9797587ab16bae76e45fb

after submitting getting in reponse -

X_SHA2_Hash - 19AB7947709CF6CB2B8415784EBD7669FCDE5D83B69EC8C716203806A3235308187668F5783F9CA0F1AE8A47808EDAB241025A8AF61A2FABC27FA6AAAEA8FFD8

generated hash code  - 
3E6427E67271B1F0732D3D95217D25EE4D7C4103C906A6CB70943498698157F48F7BECD5C7E5393CF2A489B464070A7778F15757385E8F29029CFC3F66256F05

using last snippet above.

so these are not equal so not a valid transaction.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? What is the question here? [Edit] the question and make sure it is clear what you are trying to do, and what results you get. Hint: if you make unit tests _before_ your change you will have some baseline for the parts that break later.

Comment: @jdv I have updated my question.
Please have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working

Thanks to the https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Working-php-hash-verification/td-p/65774/highlight/false

Instead of using only following three fields

> $api_login_id
>   $transaction_id
>   $amount;

I had to use all the following fields see -

```
$hashData = implode('^', [
$_POST['x_trans_id'],
$_POST['x_test_request'],
$_POST['x_response_code'],
$_POST['x_auth_code'],
$_POST['x_cvv2_resp_code'],
$_POST['x_cavv_response'],
$_POST['x_avs_code'],
$_POST['x_method'],
$_POST['x_account_number'],
$_POST['x_amount'],
$_POST['x_company'],
$_POST['x_first_name'],
$_POST['x_last_name'],
$_POST['x_address'],
$_POST['x_city'],
$_POST['x_state'],
$_POST['x_zip'],
$_POST['x_country'],
$_POST['x_phone'],
$_POST['x_fax'],
$_POST['x_email'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_company'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_first_name'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_last_name'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_address'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_city'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_state'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_zip'],
$_POST['x_ship_to_country'],
$_POST['x_invoice_num'],
]);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha512', '^'.$hashData.'^', hex2bin($signatureKey)); 
$hash = strtoupper($hash);
if($this->SHA2_Hash === $hash) {
  //valid
}
```

So use all the x_fields from authorize.net to generate hashcode

Comment: Vikas, you used the operator '==' with your first example, but then used the operator '===' in the second, it may make a difference. It is advisable to use '===' when comparing hashes.